# Regex- finding a string after the first " / " till end of line or next " / "

Tags: regex

I would like to extract data after the first occurrence of " / " until the end of line or the next instance of " / "

For example:

```
Test1 / Test 2 / Test 3
Test1 / Test2
Test 1 / Test2 / Test3
Test 1 / Test 2
```

Would return the output:

```
Test 2
Test2
Test2
Test 2
```

So far I have come up with **(?:[^/\n]+/\s){1}(.*?(?:$|\s/))** which returns the results ([see regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GF0O7n/1)):

```
Test 2 /
Test2
Test2 /
Test 2
```

I am still learning regex and having a tough time figuring out how to exclude " /" from line 1 and 3 of results so any help or guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: Eventual goal is to use this regex in a Looker Studio dashboard to extract specific data.

Comment: Did the solution below help? Please let know if you need more help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^[^\/\n]*\/\s*([^\/\n]*?)(?=\s*(?:\/|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSAfy8/1). When dealing with standalone strings, feel free remove `\n` from the pattern.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\/\n]*` - zero or more chars other than a newline and `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\/\n]*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `/` and newline as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:\/|$))` - a positive lookahead that requires a `/` or end of string after zero or more whitespaces immediately to the right of the current location.